# How can I find prime reversed numbers?

Tags: c++, reverse, primes

I have to write a program to check if the entered number has these qualifications:

> A number that is prime it self, the reverse of that number is also prime, and the number's digits are prime numbers too (Like this number: 7523).
> If the needs meet, it has to show "yes" when you enter and run the program otherwise "no".

I know both codes for prime and reverse numbers but I don't know how to merge them.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void prime_check(int x) {
  int a, i, flag = 1;
  cin >> a;
  for (i = 2; i <= a / 2 && flag == 1; i++) {
    if (a % i == 0)
      flag = 0;
  }
  if (flag == 1)
    cout << "prime";
  else
    break;
}

int main() {
  int a, r, sum = 0;
  cin >> a;
  while (a != 0) {
    r = a % 10;
    sum = (sum * 10) + r;
    a = a / 10;
  }
}
```

The program has to check each digit of the number entered to see if it is prime or not in every step, then show "yes", but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work in your eyes? Did you already use a debugger to go step for step thrugh your application? You are aware that your application never calls prime_check ?

Comment: "[...]but I don't know how to merge them." call `prime_check(a)` before the end of the while loop?

Comment: The problem is that each of your function is doing **three** things, 1) inputting the number, 2) testing the number and 3) outputting the result. To combine thiese function you need to have two function that are only testing the number. Then you can use both functions on the same number, instead of inputting two different numbers. You will need to learn how to use function parameters, to pass the inutp number to the two functions, and how to use function return values to return the result of the test. The inputting of the number and the outputting of the result go in main.

Comment: A hint: Except for 2 and 5, prime numbers cannot end in any of the digits 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8.  Since you are looking at the reversed numbers as well, that means you don't need to bother testing numbers that start with those digits because the reversed number will end in the original starting digit and so cannot be prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some changes to your code, and added comments everywhere I've made changes. Check it out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

bool prime_check(int x) {  // I have changed the datatype of this function to bool, because I want to store if all the digits are prime or not
  int i, flag = 1;  // Removed the variable a, because the function is already taking x as input
  for (i = 2; i <= x / 2 && flag == 1; i++) {
    if (x % i == 0)
      flag = 0;
  }
  return flag == 1;
}

int main() {
  int a, r, sum = 0, original;  // added original variable, to store the number added
  bool eachDigit = true;  // added to keep track of each digit
  cin >> a;
  original = a;
  while (a != 0) {
    r = a % 10;
    eachDigit = prime_check(r);  // Here Each digit of entered number is checked for prime
    sum = (sum * 10) + r;
    a = a / 10;
  }

  if (eachDigit && prime_check(original) && prime_check(sum))  // At the end checking if all the digits, entered number and the revered number are prime
    cout << "yes";
  else
    cout<< "no";

}
```

For optimization, you can check if the entered number is prime or not before starting that loop, and also you can break the loop right away if one of the digits of the entered number is not prime, Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

bool prime_check(int x) {  // I have changed the datatype of this function to bool, because I want to store if all the digits are prime or not
  int i, flag = 1;  // Removed the variable a, because the function is already taking x as input
  for (i = 2; i <= x / 2 && flag == 1; i++) {
    if (x % i == 0)
      flag = 0;
  }
  return flag == 1;
}

int main() {
  int a, r, sum = 0;
  bool eachDigit = true, entered;  // added to keep track of each digit
  cin >> a;
  entered = prime_check(a);
  while (a != 0 && entered && eachDigit) {
    r = a % 10;
    eachDigit = prime_check(r);  // Here Each digit of entered number is checked for prime
    sum = (sum * 10) + r;
    a = a / 10;
  }

  if (eachDigit && entered && prime_check(sum))  // At the end checking if all the digits, entered number and the revered number are prime
    cout << "yes";
  else
    cout<< "no";

}
```

Comment: I'd rather not use a bool for now because our teacher hasn't said anything about that yet but thank you for the hint

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site.

> I don't know how to merge them.

```
void prime_check(int n) { /*code*/ }
```

I'd understand that you don't know how to use this.

It's very easy!

```
int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  prime_check(i);
}
```

If you are confused about how the program executes, you could use a debugger to see where it goes. But since using a debugger can be a bit hard at first, I would suggest to add debug prints to see how the program executes.

This line of code prints the file and line number automatically.

```
std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "\n";
```

I'd suggest to add it at the start of every function you wish to understand.

One step further is to make it into a macro, just so that it's easy to use.

```
#define DEBUGPRINT std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "\n";
```

Check a working example here:

http://www.cpp.sh/2hpam

Note that it says `<stdin>::14` instead of the filename because it's running on a webpage.

Comment: Just add the prints, I end up using them quite often. You can't always use a debugger anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each of your functions is doing **three** things, 1) inputting the number, 2) testing the number and 3) outputting the result. To combine these functions you need to have two functions that are only testing the number. Then you can use both functions on the same number, instead of inputting two different numbers and printing two different results. You will need to use function parameters, to pass the input number to the two functions, and function return values to return the result of the test. The inputting of the number and the outputting of the result go in main. Here's an outline

```
// returns true if the number is a prime, false otherwise
bool prime_check(int a)
{
    ...
}

// returns true if the number is a reverse prime, false otherwise
bool reverse_prime_check(int a)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    if (prime_check(a) && reverse_prime_check(a))
        cout << "prime\n";
    else
        cout << "not prime\n";
}
```

I'll leave you to write the functions themselves, and there's nothing here to do the digit checks either. I'll leave you do to that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an `int` variable `num` which you want to check for your conditions, you can achieve your target by the following:

```cpp
int rev_num = 0;
bool flag = true; // Assuming 'num' satisfies your conditions, until proven otherwise

if (prime_check(num) == false) {
    flag = false;
}
else while (num != 0) {
    int digit = num % 10;
    rev_num = rev_num * 10 + digit;
    
    // Assuming your prime_check function returns 'true' and 'false'
    if (prime_check(digit) == false) {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
    
    num /= 10;
}

if (prime_check(rev_num) == false) {
    flag = false;
}

if (flag) {
    cout << "Number satisfies all conditions\n";
}
else {
    cout << "Number does not satisfy all conditions\n";
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Look at the part telling how to answer obvious homework questions

Comment: @0xbaadf00d I was trying only to provide with an optimal way of checking for the required conditions using `prime_check()`. The **definition** of the function has not been given to the student, and only the fact that a `true`/`false` value should be returned is hinted. Coming to the checking of each digit, the logic has already been successfully implemented by him/her. This code doesn't provide anything which might give away a straight-away solution, rather only tries to show the optimal way (IMO) of running the `main()` function. So IMHO, this adheres to SO guidelines.